# My "subcomponent" attribute is not being initialized

Tags: angular

I have an admin panel component with another component (wizard.component.ts) inside it referenced as .

The wizard component has a step between 1 and 3 and i load different tabs based on this step attribute with ngIf. The wizard component shows and i can see the

tags but the ngIf doesn't work because i'm assuming the step attribute isn't initialized.

I tried adding this.step = 1 to ngOnInit, constructor, and in ngOnChanges but it seems the variable doesn't initialize unless i click around and trigger some changes.

admin.component.html

```
  <div class="main-content">


      <!-- HEADER -->
      <div class="header">
        <div class="header-body ml-4">

          <h6 class="header-pretitle">
            Logged in as admin
          </h6>

          <h1 class="header-title">
            Admin panel
          </h1>

        </div>
      </div>
      <app-wizard></app-wizard>
      <!-- CARDS -->


    </div> <!-- / .main-content -->
```

wizard.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="step == 1"></div>
<div *ngIf="step == 2"></div>
<div *ngIf="step == 3"></div>
```

wizard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-wizard',
  templateUrl: './wizard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../../app.component.css','./wizard.component.css']
})
export class WizardComponent implements OnInit {
  step: number = 1
  constructor() { 
    this.step = 1
  }

  start() {
    this.step = 1
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.step = 1
    setInterval(() => {
      this.start()
    }, 1000);
  }

  ngOnChanges(){
    this.step = 1

  }

  continue(step) {
    this.step = step + 1
  }
  back(step) {
    this.step = step - 1
  }

}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Please post some example code, and a stackblitz if you think it would help

Comment: I can see the step variable value and relevant div with a quick test if I do: <div *ngIf="step == 1">Tab1</div>
<div *ngIf="step == 2">Tab2</div>
<div *ngIf="step == 3">Tab3</div>

{{step}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no need to worry about hooking into changes, the view should simply update with regards to setting a new step value. I would assume you just want something basic such as:

```
export class WizardComponent implements OnInit{
  public step: number;

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.step = 1;
  }

  public next(): void {
    this.step = this.step + 1;
  }

  public prev(): void {
    this.step = this.step - 1;
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="controls">
  <button [disabled]="step === 1" (click)="prev()">Back</button>
  <button (click)="next()">Next</button>
<div>

<div *ngIf="step === 1"> Tab 1 content </div>
<div *ngIf="step === 2"> Tab 2 content </div>
<div *ngIf="step === 3"> Tab 3 content </div>
```

Edit:

Created a basic StackBlitz for it:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nashof

Comment: Even after i made the variables and methods public it still doesn't work. I need to click on and off the admin component then it will properly initialize step and the first ngIf would pass and show Tab 1 content.

Comment: @Brendan - what do you mean click on and off the admin component exactly? Is the component already on-screen and rendered, but you need to click on it before the wizard component is initialised? Could you update your question with latest view of your code?

Comment: I set up a route /wizard goes to this wizard component, everythihng is fine... but i want this wizard component to load inside another admin component/page but it looks like just angular is not initializing the component's variables because it is a subcomponent or something, it's very weird. It's like the variable step is undefined, and only when i set it up at a different route like /wizard will it work prob because it lazy loaded?

Comment: I updated the stackblitz, this is the structure i have...https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u5sxsm and it is working in the stackblitz so i suspect there is something wrong with my angular or something up with some css. Thanks for your help

Comment: I fixed the issue. It was from an error in the admin component which logged an error but still let the program continue... i guess angular doesn't initialize the variables or calls the ngOnInit in the subcomponents unless everything is good in the parent. Thanks a lot for your help.